# electron / usb incompatible versions

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, electron, usb

I have found multiple questions similar to this but none of the solutions seems to be working for me. I am trying to use *usb* library (*https://www.npmjs.com/package/usb*) to access usb devices, and it worked perfectly as long as it was a command-line test application without Electron. I installed Electron on the Ubuntu 14 computer I'm working with *npm install electron --save-dev* and the test app provided by their website works too, but when I add my *usbtools.js* module

```
const usb = require('usb');
//...
//Example function
exports.writeBytes = function writeBytes(deviceObj, dataOut, onWriteOk) {
  deviceObj._epOut.transfer(dataOut, (err) => {});
};
//...
```

and call its exported functions from within the html page (via inline javascript) the app loads a blank page and DevTools disconnects. When i reload the page with F5, DevTools console gives me the following message:

```
/home/carl/prstatjs_dist/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:121 Uncaught Error: The module '/home/carl/prstatjs_dist/node_modules/usb/build/Release/usb_bindings.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 79. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 75. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at process.func (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at process.func [as dlopen] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:922)
    at Object.func (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at Object.func [as .node] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:735)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:648)
    at Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775)
func @ electron/js2c/asar.js:140
func @ electron/js2c/asar.js:140
Module._extensions..node @ internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:922
func @ electron/js2c/asar.js:140
func @ electron/js2c/asar.js:140
Module.load @ internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:735
Module._load @ internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:648
Module._load @ electron/js2c/asar.js:717
Module._load @ electron/js2c/asar.js:717
Module.require @ internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775
require @ internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68
bindings @ /home/carl/prstatjs_dist/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112
(anonymous) @ /home/carl/prstatjs_dist/node_modules/usb/usb.js:1
(anonymous) @ /home/carl/prstatjs_dist/node_modules/usb/usb.js:526
Module._compile @ internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880
Module._extensions..js @ internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892
Module.load @ internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:735
Module._load @ internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:648
Module._load @ electron/js2c/asar.js:717
Module._load @ electron/js2c/asar.js:717
Module.require @ internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775
require @ internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68
(anonymous) @ /home/carl/prstatjs_dist/prstat/usbtools.js:1
(anonymous) @ /home/carl/prstatjs_dist/prstat/usbtools.js:319
Module._compile @ internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880
Module._extensions..js @ internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892
Module.load @ internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:735
Module._load @ internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:648
Module._load @ electron/js2c/asar.js:717
Module._load @ electron/js2c/asar.js:717
Module.require @ internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775
require @ internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68
(anonymous) @ /home/carl/prstatjs_dist/prstat/stampanti.js:3
(anonymous) @ /home/carl/prstatjs_dist/prstat/stampanti.js:354
Module._compile @ internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880
Module._extensions..js @ internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892
Module.load @ internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:735
Module._load @ internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:648
Module._load @ electron/js2c/asar.js:717
Module._load @ electron/js2c/asar.js:717
Module.require @ internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775
require @ internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68
(anonymous) @ /home/carl/prstatjs_dist/prstat/prstat.js:2
(anonymous) @ /home/carl/prstatjs_dist/prstat/prstat.js:385
Module._compile @ internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880
Module._extensions..js @ internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892
Module.load @ internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:735
Module._load @ internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:648
Module._load @ electron/js2c/asar.js:717
Module._load @ electron/js2c/asar.js:717
Module.require @ internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775
require @ internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68
(anonymous) @ esempio_electron_codice.js:3
Show 23 more frames
```

In my understanding, this is caused by the fact that Electron provides its workframe with a Chromium-based web browser which in turn does not support the current build of node-usb. I have already tried rebuilding as suggested.
Has anyone had this problem? I need to use Electron, but I'm free to use another library to access usb devices, as long as it allows me low level control (eg: choosing interface and endpoint, I cannot just send data over the serial line).

**EDIT 1:**
node version: 13.5.0
npm version: 6.13.4
usb library version: 1.6.2 (latest, at the moment. npm fails to install anything before 1.6.0)
electron version: 7.1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily, I have found a solution:

```
$npm install electron-rebuild --dev
$./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild
```

This seems to be working, unlike the regular rebuild.